# Adding Default Settings to Theme My Login plugin

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, actions, options

I am trying to update a plugin called Theme My Login with default settings. The problem is that the updates are only applied to the database. When I log into WordPress I can't see the options updated. As instructed for default values, I used get_option before update_option.

I even made the plugin update on activation. I got the answer from a [similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26087/how-to-set-up-default-values-for-a-plugin).

Please review functions, I do not know what I could be possibly doing wrong or missing.

```
//Theme My Login Custom Settings
function nls_tml_default_activation_actions() {
    do_action( 'nls_tml_default_activation' );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'nls_tml_default_activation_actions');
add_action( 'nls_tml_default_activation', 'nls_tml_default_settings' );


function nls_tml_default_settings() {

    get_option('theme_my_login');
    update_option('theme_my_login', $nlstml);
    $nlstml = array (
        'option_value' => 'a:4:{s:10:"enable_css";b:1;s:10:"login_type";s:7:"default";s:14:"active_modules";a:6:{i:0;s:37:"custom-passwords/custom-passwords.php";i:1;s:39:"custom-user-links/custom-user-links.php";i:2;s:23:"recaptcha/recaptcha.php";i:3;s:21:"security/security.php";i:4;s:35:"themed-profiles/themed-profiles.php";i:5;s:35:"user-moderation/user-moderation.php";}s:7:"version";s:6:"6.4.10";}',
        'autoload' => 'yes',
    );

    get_option('theme_my_login_recaptcha');
    update_option('theme_my_login_recaptcha', $nlsrecap);
    $nlsrecap = array (
        'option_value' => 'a:3:{s:10:"public_key";s:7:"sitekey";s:11:"private_key";s:9:"secretkey";s:5:"theme";s:5:"light";}',
        'autoload' => 'yes',
    );

    get_option('theme_my_login_security');
    update_option('theme_my_login_security', $nlssecurity);
    $nlssecurity = array (
        'option_value' => 'a:3:{s:12:"private_site";b:0;s:13:"private_login";b:1;s:12:"failed_login";a:5:{s:9:"threshold";i:5;s:18:"threshold_duration";i:1;s:23:"threshold_duration_unit";s:4:"hour";s:16:"lockout_duration";i:24;s:21:"lockout_duration_unit";s:4:"hour";}}',
        'autoload' => 'yes',
    );

    get_option('theme_my_login_themed_profiles');
    update_option('theme_my_login_themed_profiles', $nlsprofiles);
    $nlsprofiles = array (
        'option_value' => 'a:7:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:0;}s:6:"editor";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}s:6:"author";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}s:11:"contributor";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}s:10:"subscriber";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}s:13:"wpseo_manager";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}s:12:"wpseo_editor";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}}',
        'autoload' => 'yes',
    );

  get_option('theme_my_login_moderation');
  update_option('theme_my_login_moderation', $nlsmoderation);
    $nlsmoderation = array (
        'option_value' => 'a:1:{s:4:"type";s:5:"admin";}',
        'autoload' => 'yes',
    );
}
```

Here is another example I created based on a [similar answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/263305/136510) by @Otto:

```
//Theme My Login Custom Settings
function meks_wp_parse_args( &$a, $b ) {
    $a = (array) $a;
    $b = (array) $b;
    $result = $b;
    foreach ( $a as $k => &$v ) {
        if ( is_array( $v ) && isset( $result[ $k ] ) ) {
            $result[ $k ] = meks_wp_parse_args( $v, $result[ $k ] );
        } else {
            $result[ $k ] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}


function nls_tml_default_activation_actions() {
    do_action( 'nls_tml_default_activation' );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'nls_tml_default_activation_actions');
add_action( 'nls_tml_default_activation', 'nls_tml_default_settings' );

function nls_tml_default_settings() {
    $nls_tml_defaults = array(
        'theme_my_login' => array(
            'option_value' => 'a:4:{s:10:"enable_css";b:1;s:10:"login_type";s:7:"default";s:14:"active_modules";a:6:{i:0;s:37:"custom-passwords/custom-passwords.php";i:1;s:39:"custom-user-links/custom-user-links.php";i:2;s:23:"recaptcha/recaptcha.php";i:3;s:21:"security/security.php";i:4;s:35:"themed-profiles/themed-profiles.php";i:5;s:35:"user-moderation/user-moderation.php";}s:7:"version";s:6:"6.4.10";}',
            'autoload' => 'yes',
        ),
        'theme_my_login_recaptcha' => array(
            'option_value' => 'a:3:{s:10:"public_key";s:7:"sitekey";s:11:"private_key";s:9:"secretkey";s:5:"theme";s:5:"light";}',
            'autoload' => 'yes',
        ),
        'theme_my_login_security' => array(
            'option_value' => 'a:3:{s:12:"private_site";b:0;s:13:"private_login";b:1;s:12:"failed_login";a:5:{s:9:"threshold";i:5;s:18:"threshold_duration";i:1;s:23:"threshold_duration_unit";s:4:"hour";s:16:"lockout_duration";i:24;s:21:"lockout_duration_unit";s:4:"hour";}}',
            'autoload' => 'yes',
        ),
        'theme_my_login_themed_profiles' => array(
            'option_value' => 'a:7:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:0;}s:6:"editor";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}s:6:"author";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}s:11:"contributor";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}s:10:"subscriber";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}s:13:"wpseo_manager";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}s:12:"wpseo_editor";a:2:{s:13:"theme_profile";b:1;s:14:"restrict_admin";b:1;}}',
            'autoload' => 'yes',
        ),
        'theme_my_login_moderation' => array(
            'option_value' => 'a:1:{s:4:"type";s:5:"admin";}',
            'autoload' => 'yes',
        )
    );

    // Only variables are passed to the function by reference (Strict Standards warning)
    $nls_options = get_option('plugin_options');
    $nls_options = meks_wp_parse_args($nls_options, $nls_tml_defaults);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The data wasn't fully unserialized and properly made as a multidimensional array
2. wp_parse_args() used unnecessarily.
3. get_option() used unnecessarily.

   ```
   function nls_tml_default_settings() {
   $nlstml = array(
           'enable_css'     => 1,
           'login_type'     => 'default',
           'active_modules' => array(
               'custom-passwords/custom-passwords.php',
               'custom-user-links/custom-user-links.php',
               'recaptcha/recaptcha.php',
               'security/security.php',
               'themed-profiles/themed-profiles.php',
               'user-moderation/user-moderation.php',
           ),
           'version'        => '6.4.10',
       );
       update_option( 'theme_my_login', $nlstml );

   $nlsrecap = array(
       'public_key'  => 'sitekey',
       'private_key' => 'secretkey',
       'theme'       => 'light',
   );
   update_option( 'theme_my_login_recaptcha', $nlsrecap );

   $nlssecurity = array(
       'private_site'  => '',
       'private_login' => 1,
       'failed_login'  => array(
           'threshold'               => 5,
           'threshold_duration'      => 1,
           'threshold_duration_unit' => 'hour',
           'lockout_duration'        => 24,
           'lockout_duration_unit'   => 'hour',
       ),
   );
   update_option( 'theme_my_login_security', $nlssecurity );

   $nlsprofiles = array(
       'administrator' => array(
           'theme_profile'  => 1,
           'restrict_admin' => '',
       ),
       'editor'        => array(
           'theme_profile'  => 1,
           'restrict_admin' => 1,
       ),
       'author'        => array(
           'theme_profile'  => 1,
           'restrict_admin' => 1,
       ),
       'contributor'   => array(
           'theme_profile'  => 1,
           'restrict_admin' => 1,
       ),
       'subscriber'    => array(
           'theme_profile'  => 1,
           'restrict_admin' => 1,
       ),
       'wpseo_manager' => array(
           'theme_profile'  => 1,
           'restrict_admin' => 1,
       ),
       'wpseo_editor'  => array(
           'theme_profile'  => 1,
           'restrict_admin' => 1,
       ),
   );
   update_option( 'theme_my_login_themed_profiles', $nlsprofiles );

   $nlsmoderation = array(
       'type' => 'admin',
   );
       update_option( 'theme_my_login_moderation', $nlsmoderation );

   }
   ```

   register_activation_hook( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/theme-my-login/theme-my-login.php', 'nls_tml_default_settings' );